Recursion calculating Legendre Polynom not working (segmentation fault) [C++]
I made a function in C++ that calculates the N-th Legendre polynomial and its derivative based on recursive formulas. It returns either zeros, bogus numbers or the "segmentation fault" error. I can't see what I did wrong. Care to help me out? Compiler is g++.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct LegendreValues
{
  double function_value;
  double derivative_value;
};

LegendreValues calculateLegendrePolynomAndDerivative(const int&, const double&);
double calculateLegendrePolynom(const int&, const double&);
double calculateLegendreDerivative(const int&, const double&);

int main()
{
  int N;
  LegendreValues values;
  
  cout << "Unesite red Legendreovog polinoma: " << endl;
  cin >> N;
     
  cout << calculateLegendrePolynom(N, 0.5) << "\n" << calculateLegendreDerivative(N, 0.5) << endl;
}

LegendreValues calculateLegendrePolynomAndDerivative(const int& N, const double& x)
{
  LegendreValues results;
  if (N==0)
  {
    results.function_value = 1;
    results.derivative_value = 0;

  }
  
  else if (N==1)
  {
    results.function_value = x;
    results.derivative_value = 1;

  }

  else if (N>1)
  {
    results.function_value = (1/N) * ((2*N-1) * x * calculateLegendrePolynomAndDerivative(N-1, x).function_value - (N-1) * calculateLegendrePolynomAndDerivative(N-2, x).function_value);
    
    results.derivative_value = N/(1-x*x) * ( calculateLegendrePolynomAndDerivative(N-1, x).function_value - x * calculateLegendrePolynomAndDerivative(N, x).function_value);
    
  }

  return results;
}

double calculateLegendrePolynom(const int& N, const double& x)
{
  double fval;
  if (N==0)
  {
    fval =  1;
  }
  
  else if (N==1)
  {
    fval =  x;
  }
  
  else if (N>1)
  {
    fval = (1/N) * ((2*N-1) * x * calculateLegendrePolynom(N-1, x) - (N-1) * calculateLegendrePolynom(N-2, x));
  }
  return fval;
}

double calculateLegendreDerivative(const int& N, const double& x)
{
  double dfval;
  if (N==0)
  {
    dfval =  0;
  }
  
  else if (N==1)
  {
    dfval =  1;
  }
  
  else if (N>1)
  {
    dfval = N/(1-x*x) * ( calculateLegendreDerivative(N-1, x) - x * calculateLegendreDerivative(N, x));
  }
  return dfval;
}

The recursive formulas used:
Legendre recursions
As you can see, I tried splitting the two things apart, and it still doesn't work.

This is not a [mcve].  Where are the double calculateLegendrePolynom and double calculateLegendreDerivative functions?

What do you think (1/N) evaluates as? Also, note that spawning two items from one at recursion leads to runaway exponential growth. Use memoisation if you must use recursion, but generally prefer not doing recursion at all.

@lastchance Thank you. (1/N) should simply evaluate to a double number (eg. 1/5, 1/6, etc.). N is a parameter that is given by the user at the start.

@JosipGregorić (1/N) should simply evaluate to a double number -- An integer divided by an integer will give you an integer, not a double.

@Josip Gregorić, yes your intention is that (1/N) evaluates as a double number. But the actual fact is that it will evaluate as 0 (for any N bigger than 1). Look up "integer division".

If the program reads negative numbers from stdin there will be undefined behaviour because fval and dfval are being used uninitialized. Either sanitize the input by throwing an exception after reading N < 0 or initialize fval and dfval to some values. Perhaps both.

Thank you all. Chucking in the 1.0 gets rid of the bogus numbers but not the obstinate segmentation error. It was only completely resolved by splitting the derivative and polynomial parts into seperate functions. Case closed.

@Josip Gregorić, just as a matter of interest - what did your code give when N=100?

This seems like a "press Alt + F4" moment...

@lastchance After about 13 minutes on an online (Linux) compiler, it still isn't done. I'm gonna have to cut it short to get this done on time. But, lesson learned: be careful with recursions in C++!

The (1/N) versus (1.0/N) problem is easily fixed. Less so is the runaway expansion in function evaluations if you actually compute them by recursion without memoisation (storing previously-calculated values for immediate recall).
Consider N=6, say. This spawns calls for N=5 and N=4. The first spawns calls for N=4 (which spawns further lower calls) and N=3 (which will already have been calculated); the latter spawns calls for N=3 (already calculated several times over) and 2 (ditto).
So you make many extra unnecessary function evaluations and can run out of recursion stack.
It is simpler just to iteratively (rather than recursively) calculate for i=0,1,...,N. After all, you are going to have to work these out anyway. The code below uses a vector, but you could improve that further because you only actually need to store the previous two levels at each stage - a bit like a Fibonacci sequence.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct LegendreValues
{
  double function_value;
  double derivative_value;
};

LegendreValues calculate( const int& N, const double& x );



int main()
{
  int N;
  double x;
  cout << "Enter the degree of polynomial (N >= 0): ";
  cin >> N;
  cout << "Enter the value of x ( 0 <= x < 1 ): ";
  cin >> x;
     
  LegendreValues values = calculate( N, x );
  cout << "Function:   " << values.function_value << '\n'
       << "Derivative: " << values.derivative_value << '\n';
}

LegendreValues calculate( const int& N, const double& x )
{
  vector<LegendreValues> store( 1 + N );
  for ( int i = 0; i <= N; i++ )
  {
     if ( i == 0 )
     {
        store[i] = { 1.0, 0.0 };
     }
     else if ( i == 1 )
     {
        store[i] = { x, 1.0 };
     }
     else
     {
        store[i].function_value   = ( 1.0 / i ) * ( ( 2 * i - 1 ) * x * store[i-1].function_value - ( i - 1 ) * store[i-2].function_value );
        store[i].derivative_value = i / ( 1.0 - x * x ) * ( store[i-1].function_value - x * store[i].function_value );
     }
  }
  return store[N];
}

Output:
Enter the degree of polynomial (N >= 0): 100
Enter the value of x ( 0 <= x < 1 ): 0.5
Function:   -0.060518
Derivative: -7.03317

